# Не работает перегруженный оператор >> для шаблона класса

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++

Имеется заготовка для класса четырёхугольников. Работает ввод сторон этого четырёхугольника с помощью перегруженного оператора >> , но после окончания ввода данные будто не сохраняются, т.е. остаются значения от конструктора по умолчанию (в данном случае 0). Не понятно почему так происходит, причём значения обнуляются именно по окончании ввода.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Array.h"
template<class T>
class Rect
{
private:
    T m_left, m_top;
    T m_right, m_bottom;
public:
    Rect(): m_left(0), m_right(0), m_top(0), m_bottom(0){}
    Rect(T left, T right, T top, T bottom): m_left(left), m_right(right), m_top(top), m_bottom(bottom) {}
    Rect(const Rect &R): m_left(R.m_left), m_right(R.m_right), m_top(R.m_top), m_bottom(R.m_bottom) {}

    ~Rect() {}

    Rect& operator=(const Rect& R){ 
        m_left = R.m_left;
        m_right = R.m_right;
        m_top = R.m_top;
        m_bottom = R.m_bottom;
        return *this; 
    }
    template <class T> friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Rect<T> R);
    template <class T> friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Rect<T> R);
};
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    //Array<Rect<int>> a(1);
    Rect<int> R;
    cin >> R;
    cout << R;
    return 0;
}
template<class T>
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Rect<T> R) {
    puts("Введите левую сторону: ");
    is >> R.m_left;
    puts("Введите верхнюю сторону: ");
    is >> R.m_top;
    puts("Введите правую сторону: ");
    is >> R.m_right;
    puts("Введите нижнюю сторону: ");
    is >> R.m_bottom;
    return is;
}
template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Rect<T> R) {
    os << "Верхняя сторона: " << R.m_top;
    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы передаёте `Rect<T>` по значению, из-за чего вы записываете во временную копию.

Замените сигнатуру на

```
template<class T>
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Rect<T> &R)
```